# Why is my patch not being applied in my docker container?

Tags: docker, patch-package

I'm using patch-package to patch node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/helpers/configuration.js

The patch works fine locally.

However, try as I might, I can't get Docker to apply the patch when I containerise my software.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.17.6
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY patches .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The folder 'patches' is in my root directory and contains the required patch (/patches/oidc-provider+7.13.0.patch).

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why this is happening, but I have got around it by taking out the `RUN npm install` instruction and copying my dependencies into the container (i.e. remove node_modules from dockerignore).